# Renesas M32R Processor preocedural call and returns

Tags: assembly, risc

How do I create a procedure in an Renesas M32R ISA? how do I call it and how do I return it? There aren't many documentation on this ISA on the internet.
Is it the same as Arm's procedure call?

Comment: The instruction set reference [is readily available on Renesas' website](https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/products/microcontrollers-microprocessors/m32r/m32r-ecu/32185.html#documents) (filter on "User's Manual: Software" to make it easier to find).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a procedure as:

```
my_funct:
    <instruction>
```

Call this procedure using Branch and link (bl).

```
BL my_func
```

> BL causes an unconditional branch to the address specified by the label and puts the return address in R14.

See Chapter3 of https://www.renesas.com/eu/en/doc/products/mpumcu/001/rej09b0112_32fpusm.pdf